# Understanding Titan Traversals

Tags: traversal, titan, tinkerpop

I am trying to write a highly scalable system with titandb. I have a situation where some nodes are highly connected. 
Imagine the following example at much larger scale.

[image: Example Graph]

Now I have the following situations:

1. I want to find all the freinds of node **X**.
2. I want to find a specific friend of node **X** for example **5**.

For scenario 1 I do: `g.V(X).out(friend).toList()`. For scenario 2 I do: `g.V(X).out(friend).hasId(5).next()`. Both of these traversals will work but scale poorly as **X** gets more friends. Can I optimise this situation by putting more information on the edge label ? For example if on the edge between **X** and **5** I change the label to `freind_with_5` will the following be faster:

```
`g.V(X).out(freind_with_5).next()`
```

From my understanding this will be faster as only 1 edge will be traversed. However, if I make such a change to my edge labels how would I find all the friends of **X** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could encode data into your edge label, but I would say that do that at the cost of complicating your graph schema considerably and, as you note, make it hard to do simple things like "find all my friends". I don't think you should take that approach.

The preferred method for dealing with this is with [vertex-centric indices](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html#vertex-indexes). If you denormalize any data to your edges, you should do it with those indices in mind (and not by encoding that data into the edge label).  Put some unique identifier for the friend on the "friend" edge and index that.

If your supernodes are especially large (millions+ edges) you should also consider Titan's [vertex partitioning](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/graph-partitioning.html) feature.